# Как вывести div с конкретным элементом при клике на него в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я вывожу элементы массива в виде списка. Сейчас при клике на элемент, он добавляется вниз списка. Но я хочу вывести(отрендерить) рядом отдельный div с этим элементом.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class List extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
                    <li key={index} onClick={() => this.props.addToArray(item.id)}>{item.id}</li>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        menu: [
            {
                link: 'link1',
                id: 'Articles'
            },
            {
                link: 'link2',
                id: 'Contacts'
            },
            {
                link: 'link3',
                id: 'Posts'
            },
            {
                link: 'link1',
                id: 'Lorem'
            },
            {
                link: 'link2',
                id: 'Ipsum'
            },
            {
                link: 'link3',
                id: 'Test'
            }
        ]
    }

    addToArray = (id) => {
        this.setState(state => {
            return {
                menu: [...state.menu, {id, link: 'link'}]
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List items={this.state.menu} addToArray={this.addToArray}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: @WVFFLIFE Проблема в том, что я не хочу добавлять элемент в массив(как это сейчас в коде). Вместо этого я не знаю как отрендерить рядом div с этим же элементом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

```js
class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const {activeElement, items, setActiveElement} = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <div style={{marginRight: 50}}>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index} onClick={() => setActiveElement(item)}>
              {item.id}
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
        {activeElement ? (
          <div>
            <h2>{activeElement.id}</h2>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    activeElement: null,
    menu: [
      {
        link: "link1",
        id: "Articles"
      },
      {
        link: "link2",
        id: "Contacts"
      },
      {
        link: "link3",
        id: "Posts"
      },
      {
        link: "link1",
        id: "Lorem"
      },
      {
        link: "link2",
        id: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        link: "link3",
        id: "Test"
      }
    ]
  };

  setActiveElement = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      activeElement: item
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List 
          items={this.state.menu}
          activeElement={this.state.activeElement} 
          setActiveElement={this.setActiveElement} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это не то, что нужно, то попробуйте сформулировать вопрос по другому, потому что не понятно, что с этим элементом должно дальше происходить.

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index} onClick={() => this.props.addToArray(item.id, item.link)}>
            {item.id}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menu: [
      {
        link: "link1",
        id: "Articles"
      },
      {
        link: "link2",
        id: "Contacts"
      },
      {
        link: "link3",
        id: "Posts"
      },
      {
        link: "link1",
        id: "Lorem"
      },
      {
        link: "link2",
        id: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        link: "link3",
        id: "Test"
      }
    ],
    newMenu: []
  };

  addToArray = (id, link) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        newMenu: [...state.newMenu, { id, link }]
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="App">
        <List items={this.state.menu} addToArray={this.addToArray} />
        <List items={this.state.newMenu} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Ссылка на песочницу](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-star-vof2p)